# How to custom Vitamio widget?

Tags: java, android, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I'm using Vitamio plugin to play live streaming. It works well. But I cannot custom its VideoPlayer. Anybody can show me how to :

1/ auto play when streaming is loaded. I'm using this code but it is not efficient

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

2/ hide the file name on control bar. I tried to use `mMediaController.setFileName("")` and `mMediaController.setInfoView(null)` but the file name is still shown.

Answer (score 2):

1) Their example uses

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        if (loadingDialog.isShowing()) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    }
});
```

2) Are you using Vitamio Bundle as a library?

If so, just open res/layout/mediacontroller.xml and edit the filename TextView to add visibility invisible (using gone breaks the ui)
Here you can customize as much as you want

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/mediacontroller_file_name"
  style="@style/MediaController_Text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:singleLine="true" 
  android:visibility="invisible"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mVideoView.setMediaController()
```

sets the MediaController widget to be displayed. Just create your own from scratch.